# framed equations

Tags: equations, framed

I'm aware of possibilities to frame an "important" equation in Latex as the one suggested in mathmode for instance but I thought it would be nice to have a dedicated environment instead of putting frames or boxes around equations on the fly. So I came up with what follows by just adapting the existing equation environment:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{red!80}{red!20}}%
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fequation}{%
%\setlength\abovedisplayskip{3pt}
%\setlength\belowdisplayskip{3pt}
  \incr@eqnum%
  \mathdisplay@push%
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue%
  \MakeFramed{%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
  \FrameRestore}%
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \endMakeFramed\noindent%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec
\begin{equation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{equation}
porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non
\begin{fequation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{fequation}
vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.
\begin{fequation}
\begin{aligned}
&\cos t=\pi\\
&\sin t=-\pi
\end{aligned}
\end{fequation}
vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.
\begin{fequation}
\biggl(\int_\Omega \frac{t^2}{t+1}\D{t}\biggr)=1
\end{fequation}
\end{document}
```

I've been playing around the `\vspace*` as well as `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` commands for tuning but I am wondering how to control the vertical white space between main text and framed equations? Also, any improvement that you find interesting is welcome.

Comment: use the package `empheq`, it has it already

Comment: ah, too bad, I missed that one! I'll have a look at the code to see what I can do. But still, what I do not understand in the provided code, is that `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` control the vertical space inside the box? Why not outside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is your code with a simple box:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\MBox

\newenvironment{fequation}{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}%
  \par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\MBox}   
  \minipage{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax} 
  \equation\strut%
}{%
  \endequation%
  \endminipage%
  \end{lrbox}\fcolorbox{red!80}{red!20}{\usebox\MBox}%
  \ignorespacesafterend\par\noindent}%     
\begin{document}
Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec
%
\begin{equation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{equation}
%
por
%
\begin{fequation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{fequation}
%
vitae, 
\begin{fequation}
\begin{aligned}
&\cos t=\pi\\
&\sin t=-\pi
\end{aligned}
\end{fequation}
%
vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.
\begin{fequation}
\biggl(\int_\Omega \frac{t^2}{t+1}\D{t}\biggr)=1
\end{fequation}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it is nice and better vertically centered than what I had. Is it because the minipage? It looks like there is a small spurious horitontal space before vitae? probably because there is a missing % after `\endminipage`

Comment: yes, you are right. I edited my answer

Answer (score 4):

With `tcolorbox` help it's easy to declare your own environments for boxed equations

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{colback=red!20, colframe=red!80}

\newtcolorbox{fequation}[1][]{ams equation,size=small,#1}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{equation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{fequation}
\cos t=\pi
\end{fequation}
vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.
\begin{fequation}[ams align]
\cos t&=\pi\\
\sin t&=-\pi
\end{fequation}
vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.
\begin{fequation}
\biggl(\int_\Omega \frac{t^2}{t+1}\D{t}\biggr)=1
\end{fequation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `float`to create your own floating environment, with the `boxed` option:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{frameequation}{hbtp}{feq}[section]
\floatname{frameequation}{Equation}

\newcommand{\freq}[2]{%
\begin{frameequation}%
\ensuremath{\hfill #1 \hfill}%
\caption{#2}
\end{frameequation}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Some math topic}

\lipsum[1]

\freq{\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=???}{One}

\lipsum[1]

\freq{\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=???}{Two}

\lipsum[1]

\freq{\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=???}{Three}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `empheq` package mentioned by Herbert, there's the package `mdframed` that provides similar functionality. A nice feature of the `mdframed` package is there's no complication if the block to be framed contains a page break -- the frame around it will also cross the page boundary. :-)

Comment: yes, I'm aware of this package but for an equation (which won't break along pages) it may not be necessary even though it would still work.

Comment: Just a quick note -- the `mdframed` package is not the same as the `framed` package you're loading in your MWE. The `mdframed` package lets you define your own environments (which could include, say, an equation), so that's why I thought it might meet your needs.

Comment: @pluton: You can define the environment with the option `nobreak` ;-)

Comment: I know that your package would be perfectly working for this case but a simple box would be enough I guess, unless you have something super nice in mind :)