# How can I box multiple aligned equations?

Tags: equations, boxes

This question is two-fold. In my document, I currently have boxes around single equations like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setlength\fboxsep{0.25cm}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.4pt}
\boxed{\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=0. 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

- I would now like to be able to adjust the `fboxsep` for each side top and bottom margins separately from the left and right margins
- Also, I would like to box - in the same style - multiple equations that are aligned.

How can I do these?

(a) shows the output of corresponding to the box in the MWE, (b) shows an example of what I'd like to get from adjusting the left and right margins independently of the top and bottom ones, (c) shows what how I'd like - in a consistent manner - the boxing of equations that are currently in an `align` environment (inside a `subequations`):

[image]

Comment: have you seen [Black and white emphasis for \boxed?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42315) and the links within?

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, I checked previous related questions and didn't find what I am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `empheq` package is your friend. The wide box is made with a normal box, with some space left and right, that you can adjust to your likings.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{equation}
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = 0
\end{empheq}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0 \\
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about adjusting the vertical margins?

Comment: @User17670 Use `\setlength\fboxsep{0.5cm}` which will increase the space around the formula in all directions. Then you can adapt `\widefbox` again.

Answer (score 16):

`tcolorbox` package provides commands to produce colorful framed boxes which can also be applied to `math` environments.

`\tcboxmath` and `\tcbhighmath` commands add boxes to math expressions. The second one is used to highlight some part of a math expression, even inside a boxed one. Default configurations for these kind of boxes look like

```
\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath{\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=0.}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath{\tcbhighmath{\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}}=0.}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

If equation number must be included into the box, `theorems` library provides `ams equation`, `ams align` and `ams gather` environments. Two customized examples:

```
\newtcolorbox{mymathbox}[1][]{colback=white, sharp corners, #1}

\begin{mymathbox}[ams equation]
\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{mymathbox}

\begin{mymathbox}[ams gather, title=two equations, colframe=blue!30!black]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x = \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{mymathbox}
```

[image]

Finally, `tcboxes` can be used to define boxes compatible with `empheq` package to box multiline equations (no number inside box).

```
\newtcbox{\othermathbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base, 
          enhanced, sharp corners, colback=black!10, colframe=red!30!black, 
          drop fuzzy shadow, left=1em, top=2em, right=3em, bottom=4em}
```

`left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` values define extra margins inside the box.

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\othermathbox]{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{empheq}
```

[image]

The complete code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mymathbox}[1][]{colback=white, sharp corners, #1}

\newtcbox{\othermathbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base, enhanced, sharp corners, colback=black!10, colframe=red!30!black, drop fuzzy shadow, left=1em, top=2em, right=3em, bottom=4em}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath{\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=0.}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath{\tcbhighmath{\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}}=0.}
\end{equation}

\begin{mymathbox}[ams equation]
\bar{\nabla}^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{mymathbox}

\begin{mymathbox}[ams gather, title=two equations, colframe=blue!30!black]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x = \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{mymathbox}

\begin{empheq}[box=\othermathbox]{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For part A, `\fbox` uses `\kern\fboxsep` to make horizontal whitespace around the boxed thing, and then `\@frameb@x` uses `\vskip\fboxsep` to wrap it in vertical whitespace. So one quick-and dirty-solution would be to introduce two separate lengths, `\fboxseph` and `\fboxsepv`, and reimplement the commands word-for-word, only using different lengths for vertical and horisontal space.

Use `\longboxed` instead of `\boxed` after you include the following  in the preamble:

```
\newlength\fboxseph
\newlength\fboxsepv

\setlength\fboxsepv{0.25cm}
\setlength\fboxseph{1cm}

\makeatletter

\def\longboxed#1{\leavevmode\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\color@begingroup%
\kern\fboxseph{\m@th$\displaystyle #1 $}\kern\fboxseph%
\color@endgroup }\my@frameb@x\relax}

\def\my@frameb@x#1{%
\@tempdima\fboxrule \advance\@tempdima \fboxsepv \advance\@tempdima \dp\@tempboxa\hbox {%
\lower \@tempdima \hbox {%
\vbox {\hrule\@height\fboxrule \hbox{\vrule\@width\fboxrule #1 \vbox{%
\vskip\fboxsepv \box\@tempboxa \vskip\fboxsepv}#1 \vrule\@width\fboxrule }%
\hrule \@height \fboxrule }}}}

\makeatother
```

Have no idea about Part B, though.