# Equation numbers for boxed multiline equations

Tags: equations, numbering, boxes, subequations, empheq

I am attempting to set a box around multiline equations is LaTeX using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}
z &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k \\
&\qquad\qquad + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s \\
&\qquad\qquad + t + u + v + w + x + y
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the equations are automatically labelled (1a), (1b), and (1c).  Since this is only one equation, how can I label the whole box simply as (1)?

Comment: `align` is defined by `amsmath`, which you don't mention.  you can use `split` instead of `align` to get only one equation number.  also, i'm not sure why you need `subequations` since there's only one.

Comment: Thanks barbara.  Could you state what exact lines of code would allow this?  I am not sure how to generate an equation box that spans multiple lines without `subequations` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/how-can-i-box-multiple-aligned-equations).

Comment: @barbarabeeton - the `empheq` package loads the `amsmath` package (and its `subequations` and `align` environments).

Comment: @Mico -- just proving that i don't use `empheq` enough to know that.  thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- I don't use it much either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could omit the `subequations` environment specifiers, change `align` to `equation` (in the supplemental argument to `empheq`), and use a `split` environment *inside* `empheq` to achieve the alignment objectives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{equation}
\begin{split}
z &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k \\
&\qquad\qquad + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s \\
&\qquad\qquad + t + u + v + w + x + y
\end{split}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```