# Box around equations in align environment and no indentation

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, boxes, framed

I have the following code and I want to do two things to it.First, I want to have the output maximally on the left, that is I do not want any indentation of the stuff in the align environment, I want them to be in the same alignment as my text.The second thing I want to do is place a box around the entire content of the align environment. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be most grateful!

```
I want this to be left-aligned in the same position as the following equations.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin= 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{qtree}
    \tikzset{small/.style={level distance=25pt,sibling distance=0pt}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&\llbracket \text{before} (\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket                         \\
&\equiv \lambda t. \Big(\neg \exists t' \big[t' \le t \wedge \llbracket (\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \big] \Big)                        \tag{definition}\\
&\equiv \lambda t. \Big(\forall t' \neg \big[t' \le t \wedge \llbracket (\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \big] \Big)                    \tag{$\neg (\exists x)[\mathscr{P}(x)] \equiv  (\forall x)\neg[\mathscr{P}(x)]$}\\
&\equiv \lambda t. \Big(\forall t' \neg \big[t' \le t \wedge (\llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \vee \llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') ) \big] \Big)                   \tag{point-wise disjunction}\\
&\equiv \lambda t. \Big(\forall t'  \neg \Big[ \Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \vee \Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \Big)                           \tag{$\mathscr{A}\wedge(\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{C}) \equiv (\mathscr{A} \wedge \mathscr{B}) \vee (\mathscr{A} \wedge \mathscr{C}))$}\\
&\equiv \lambda t. \Big(\forall t'  \Big[ \neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \wedge \neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \Big)   \tag{De Morgan}\\
&\equiv \lambda t.  \Big[ \forall t'\neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \wedge \forall t'\neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big]          \tag{$\forall x[\mathscr{P}(x) \vee \mathscr{R}(x)] \equiv \forall x[\mathscr{P}(x)] \vee \forall x[\mathscr{R}(x)]$}\\
&\equiv \lambda t.  \Big[ \forall t'\neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \wedge \lambda t. \Big[ \forall t'\neg\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \tag{point-wise conjunction}\\
&\equiv \lambda t.  \Big[ \neg\exists t'\Big(t' \le t \wedge \llbracket \mathscr{B}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \wedge \lambda t. \Big[ \neg\exists t'\Big(t' \le t \wedge\llbracket \mathscr{C}) \rrbracket(t') \Big) \Big] \tag{$\neg (\exists x)[\mathscr{P}(x)] \equiv  (\forall x)\neg[\mathscr{P}(x)]$}\\
& \equiv \llbracket \text{before} (\mathscr{B}) \wedge \text{before} (\mathscr{C})\rrbracket \tag{definition}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you give us a minimal but complete working example, it will be easy to help you. This is, complete your code starting with `\documentcass` and finishing with `\end{document}` and insert a preamble with all needed packages.

Comment: Done! Most packages may be irrelevant for this but I am just listing them anyway in case of potential conflicts.

Comment: For boxes around equations: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109900/1952

Comment: Your code doesn't compile in my system. Something is missing.

Comment: Please minimize your code. It makes it much easier for us. If you get in conflicts later, just do another question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `falling` and `tikzmark` to place a box around he entire set of equations:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- Also note the trailing `&` on the `F = ma`. This is required to get the equations al the way to the left.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {\strut};}
\newcommand*{\xSep}{2.0pt}
\newcommand*{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
        \coordinate (Right Side) at (#3.south -| current page text area.north east);
        \draw [#1] 
            (#2.north) rectangle %(current page text area.east);
            (Right Side);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
I want this to be left-aligned in the same position as the following equations, 
with no indentation from the left margin
\begin{flalign*}
\mytikzmark{start}
F & = ma &&\text{Newtons famous equation.} &\\
E &= mc^2 && \text{Einstein's discovery!}\mytikzmark{end}
\end{flalign*}
\DrawBox[draw=red, thick]{start}{end}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost it, but I also want to have comments to the right of each equation line. How may I incorporate this?

Comment: @OrestXherija: Adding comments to an equation is quite a different question from adding a box and no indentation. I have updated the solution to allow for comments on the equations, but for future reference, it is better to ask separate questions (so that they can be of help to more people).

Comment: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
I want this to be left-aligned in the same position as the following equations,
with no indentation from the left margin
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
F & = ma    &&  \text{Newtons famous equation.} &   \\
E &= mc^2   &&  \text{Einstein's discovery!}    
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

This is slightly simplified and less fancy than what proposed in @Peter Grill answer.

I used `empheq` package. As stated in package documentation:

> The `empheq` package can best be described as a visual markup extension to `amsmath`. In short it offers a) a multi line equivalent of `\boxed` from `amsmath` and b) a way to produce arbitrary delimiters that span entire math displays.