# Boxed multi-line equations with equation numbers outside the box

Tags: equations, amsmath, box, texdoc

How to combine the following two equations both being inside a single box and the equation numbers outside the box. Thanks

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{L_{l+1}=P_ka_{L+1}^T\left(a_{L+1}P_ka_{L+1}^T+I_N\right)^{-1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{L_{l+1}=\frac{P_ka_{L+1}^T}{a_{k+1}P_ka_{L+1}^T+I_N}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The answer to your question can be found in the `amsmath` users guide in section 4.7.  `texdoc amsldoc`.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109906/218142

Comment: I want with " amsmath " just as in my example above. Can anyone do it please? Thanks!

Comment: As LaTeXereXeTaL links to, use `empheq`. There is no `amsmath` only solution.

Comment: I am sure there must be!

Comment: What makes you so sure? `\boxed` is basically nothing more than a thin wrapper around `\fbox` and it simply does not support what you require. That's why there are extensions to `amsmath` like `mathools` and `empheq` (specifically, `empheq` loads `mathtools` which loads `amsmath`).

Comment: @campa, @ daleif, could you please apply mathtools or emphep on above example in the most simple way. Thanks!